# "En quelques années" ou "dans quelques années"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-temps

> Il a vite compris qu'il ne deviendrait pas riche **en** quelques années
>   comme il l'avait pensé d'abord.

Pourquoi emploie-t-on **en** ici ? Je pensais qu'il fallait employer **dans** comme il s'agit d'un contexte futur.

Comment: @LPH Vous avez raison, en effet c'est une faute de frappe. Je vais modifier ma question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deux contextes sont possibles, chacun exigeant l'une des deux prépositions (l'autre ne convenant pas du tout).

Si l'on veut exprimer que le temps que cela pourrait prendre ou devra prendre est celui de quelques années alors il faut « en » ;

- Il a vite compris qu'il ne deviendrait pas riche en quelques années comme il l'avait pensé d'abord.

Si l'on veut exprimer que le moment venu lorsque l'on devient riche se trouve dans le futur à une date qui s'évalue en ajoutant au moment présent quelques années, alors on utilise « dans » ;

- Il a vite compris qu'il ne deviendrait pas riche dans quelques années comme il l'avait pensé d'abord.

Un contexte pour cette dernière possibilité pourrait être quelque chose de la sorte suivante ;

On le lui avait dit, répété, expliqué : dans quelques années il serait riche et il l'avait cru ; cependant des indications lui ont montré le contraire. Il a vite compris qu'il ne deviendrait pas riche dans quelques années comme il avait pensé d'abord. Il voit maintenant les choses différemment, tout cela n'est que mensonge.